# Drawing Ferrers Diagrams in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

How would I draw this (Ferrers diagram) in tikz?

[image]

Comment: In the examples I saw, parts with different number of rows are not equalized in height.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome! This is one way.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
 \fill foreach \Z [count=\Y] in {6,3,3,2,1}
  {foreach \X in {1,...,\Z} 
  {(\X,-\Y) circle[radius=3pt]}};
 \fill[xshift=8cm] foreach \Z [count=\Y] in {5,4,3,1,1}
  {foreach \X in {1,...,\Z} 
  {(\X,-\Y) circle[radius=3pt]}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This reproduces the diagram you show.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{ferrers}[1][4em]
 {%
  \leavevmode
  \hbox\bgroup
    \def\\{\unskip\cr\noalign{\hskip#1}}%
    \valign\bgroup&##\cr
 }
 {%
  \unskip\crcr\egroup
  \egroup
 }

\newcommand{\row}[1]{%
  \hbox{$\activatem\romannumeral\number\number#1 000 \unskip$}\vskip 0.5em plus 3em
}
\newcommand{\activatem}{%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`m \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\bullet\hskip1em}%
  \mathcode`m="8000
}

\begin{document}

\begin{ferrers}
\row{6}
\row{3}
\row{3}
\row{2}
\row{1}
\\
\row{5}
\row{4}
\row{3}
\row{1}
\row{1}
\row{1}
\end{ferrers}

\end{document}
```

New lines and spaces in the `ferrers` environment are irrelevant, so you can also input the same as

```latex
\begin{ferrers}
\row{6} \row{3} \row{3} \row{2} \row{1} \\
\row{5} \row{4} \row{3} \row{1} \row{1} \row{1}
\end{ferrers}
```

[image]

A version that doesn't equalize the two parts.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{ferrers}[1][4em]
 {%
  \leavevmode
  %\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  \hbox\bgroup
    \def\\{\unskip\vfill\cr\noalign{\hskip#1}}%
    \valign\bgroup&##\cr
 }
 {%
  \unskip\vfill\crcr\egroup
  \egroup
  %\end{tabular}
 }

\newcommand{\row}[1]{%
  \hbox{$\activatem\romannumeral\number\number#1 000 \unskip$}\vskip 0.5em
}
\newcommand{\activatem}{%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`m \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\bullet\hskip1em}%
  \mathcode`m="8000
}

\begin{document}

\begin{ferrers}
\row{6}
\row{3}
\row{3}
\row{2}
\row{1}
\\
\row{5}
\row{4}
\row{3}
\row{1}
\row{1}
\row{1}
\end{ferrers}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In both version you can use `\begin{ferrers}[6em]` (with whatever length) to set the space between the parts (default is 4em).